# How to replace contents of a regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

My brain just may not be working tonight but I need some help.

I have this string

[9][1][1][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][9][a][b][ ][ ]

And I want to replace anything that is in the bracket with a different character.
To simplify lets just say x.

It wont be x however. I will be running this though a function to change each number to a color code.

So it will look like this when done.
[x][x][x][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][x][x][x][ ][ ]

I have tried some ridiculous string.replace() function but to no avail.

EDIT:
Each number I run this this function

```
public ChatColor getColor(String id)
{
    ChatColor color = ChatColor.WHITE;
    if(id == "0") color = ChatColor.BLACK;
    if(id == "1") color = ChatColor.DARK_BLUE;
    if(id == "2") color = ChatColor.DARK_GREEN;
    if(id == "3") color = ChatColor.DARK_AQUA;
    if(id == "4") color = ChatColor.DARK_RED;
    if(id == "5") color = ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE;
    if(id == "6") color = ChatColor.GOLD;
    if(id == "7") color = ChatColor.GRAY;
    if(id == "8") color = ChatColor.DARK_GRAY;
    if(id == "9") color = ChatColor.BLUE;
    if(id == "a") color = ChatColor.GREEN;
    if(id == "b") color = ChatColor.AQUA;
    if(id == "c") color = ChatColor.RED;
    if(id == "d") color = ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE;
    if(id == "e") color = ChatColor.YELLOW;
    if(id == "f") color = ChatColor.WHITE;

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Don't compare strings using `==`.  Use `.equals` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, why not pull out each individual character on the string, apply some function to change the character to fit some color code that you have specified, and reassemble the string afterwords. You could run the loop within a loop and do this as many times as you wanted (what I mean, is put the bottom for loop into another for loop depending on the number of iterations the process was going to take and the various conditions). As an example, you have:

```
String s = [9][1][1][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][9][a][b][ ][ ]
```

Let us next loop through each of the characters, and at each character c, replace the characters based on some conditions. There are multiple options here for the replacement and I just left comments in the relevant places I might try it. Here is the proposed for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        

    //Process char

    //Add new character to a new string here and then reassemble the string

}
```

Comment: This would be one for sure way of doing it. I may use this if I can find a regex example. This may even be faster then using a regex. But then again I'm also here to learn new things.

Comment: Great. Glad this helps. I will think about the regex approach a little more to see if I can come up with something tangible. For now, this basic approach should do the job. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using look-aheads.

```
    String input = "[9][1][1][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][9][a][b][ ][ ]";
    // Map of color codes.
    HashMap<String,String> colorMap; 
    String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\[)\\S*?(?=\\])","x");
```

Based on your comment on devnull's answer, it sounds like you actually want a mapped replacement:

```
    String input = "[9][1][1][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][9][a][b][ ][ ]";
    // Map of color codes.

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        String current = Integer.toString(i, 16);
        input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\[)" + current + "(?=\\])",getColor(current));
    }
    System.out.println(input);
```

Note that this solution assumes that `ChatColor` has a reasonable `toString` method.

Comment: Let me try this and see what happens. Thanks for your time! I will let you know here in a few.

Comment: What would I initialize colorMap too?

Comment: @Snhp9, I will update my answer based on your update.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you parse 16 times the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, You are absolutely correct in that this is not computationally efficient. However, computational efficiency was not one of the concerns that the OP has expressed, through his original post or his comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

A way using split:

```
String s = "[1][1][4][2][6][d][][][][a][8]";

String[] tok = s.split("(?<=\\[)(?=[0-9a-f]\\])|(?<=\\[[0-9a-f])(?=\\])");
String result = "";

for (int i=0; i<tok.length; i++) {
    if (i%2==1) {
        result += getColor(tok[i]);
    } else {
        result += tok[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you might want to do is to create a regex Pattern, then create a Matcher from it and use that to replace the characters in the string.

Here are the two APIs for the classes which hopefully give all the information that you need (including what the different regex symbols mean).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Good sources from google if you have any questions on how to use these classes:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Seeing the other's answers, this might be what it doing in the backend when String.replaceAll() is being called, so this is no longer the best solution. I would say what I'm about to say as a comment in their answers, but my reputation is to low. What you could do is have more than one replace statement for each code.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\[1\\]", "[x]"));
s = s.replaceAll("\\[2\\]", "[y]"));
s = s.replaceAll("\\[3\\]", "[z]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match:

`\[([^\s])\]`

and then replace with `[x]`.

#### Regex Demo

http://regex101.com/r/mH4mH1

Comment: This would work but I need to replace each number with a color code essentially. So each number that different will have a different color code.

Comment: @Snhp9, Can you please include an example of that in your code